# looping through an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary

How do I loop through all objects in a NSMutableDictionary regardless of the keys?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

A standard way would look like this

```
for(id key in myDict) {
    id value = [myDict objectForKey:key];
    [value doStuff];
}
```

Comment: If only there were a way of doing something like: `for (id key, value in myDict)` that would be perfect.

Comment: Better to iterate through keys though (i.e. `id key in myDict.allKeys`), rather than the dictionary. This allows you to mutate the dictionary, which might be what you want to do.

Answer (score 30):

you can use

```
[myDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    // do something with key and obj
}];
```

if your target OS supports blocks.

Answer (score 23):

You can use `[dict allValues]` to get an `NSArray` of your values. Be aware that it doesn't guarantee any order between calls.

Comment: I would use this one over the (id key in dictionary), especially on a mutable dictionary, since the latter throws a nasty error if the dictionary is modified while being enumerated.

Comment: "it doesn't guarantee" - this is frequently needed (most languages have a version of dictionary that DOES guarantee order) - does it *in practice* preserve order?

Comment: @Adam On MacOS X, I had pretty mixed up order (not order of insertion, not alphabetic, nothing), but consistent between calls.

Comment: Why use a NSDictionary if the mappings don't matter?

Comment: @stephen Usually it matters somewhere and doesn't elsewhere. You also get the unique key constraint that might be useful for some cases.

Answer (score 5):

1. For simple loop, fast enumeration is a bit faster than block-based loop
2. It's easier to do concurrent or reverse enumeration with block-based enumeration than with fast enumeration
   When looping with  NSDictionary you can get key and value in one hit with a block-based enumerator, whereas with fast enumeration you have to use the key to retrieve the value in a separate message send

in fast enumeration

```
for(id key in myDictionary) {
   id value = [myDictionary objectForKey:key];
  // do something with key and obj
}
```

in Blocks :

```
[myDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

   // do something with key and obj
  }];
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to assign value to a variable. You can access it directly with `myDict[key]`.

```
    for(id key in myDict) {
        NSLog(@"Key:%@ Value:%@", key, myDict[key]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the Dicts Enumerator. Here is some sample code from Apple:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myDictionary objectEnumerator];
id value;

while ((value = [enumerator nextObject])) {
    /* code that acts on the dictionary’s values */
}
```